# Intersection of n rectangles - Maximum number of regions where exactly k rectangles intersect

Tags: algorithm, geometry, complexity-theory, computational-geometry

Imagine `n` axis-aligned rectangles (specified by its position `(x,y)`, width and height). The rectangles are aligned in a way so that the `i`-th rectangle  **necessarily** intersects with the `(i+1)`-th. For example let `n = 3`, then `1` necessarily intersects with `2` and `2` with `3`. It is important to mention that this is **not** transitive; `3` *can* intersect with `1` but there is no guarantee (see figure for two valid alignment examples).

[image: Examples for valid alignments of <code>n=3</code> rectangles. The right sub-image shows a worst-case alignment.]

What I'm now looking for is the maximum possible number of regions where **exactly** `k = 2,...,n` rectangles intersect with each other (these regions are shown in the figure). In other words, I'm looking for a worst-case alignment of `n` rectangles so that the number of regions where exactly `k` rectangles intersect reaches its maximum. *Theoretical*, the maximum possible number of regions where exaclty `k` rectangles intersect is `n over k` (the binomial coefficient). However, this formula is *geometrical* only valid for `n < 4` as it is not possible to align (and to draw) rectangles for `n >= 4` so that in the worst-case `n over k` regions exist where exactly `k` rectangles intersect.

The first sub-image of the figure shows the worst-case alignment for `n = 3`. There are `3 over 2 = 3` regions where exactly two rectangles intersect and `3 over 3 = 1` region where exactly three rectangles intersect. The second sub-image also shows a valid alignment for three rectangles however this is not a worst-case alignment as, for example, there is no region where exactly three rectangles intersect.

Comment: Can you explain in a little more detail what the input and expected output is?

Comment: @m69 The algorithm should take a set of `n` rectangles and align them in a way so that the regions, where exactly `k = 2,...,n` rectangles overlap reaches its maximum. Such an alignment is shown within the first-subimage of the figure for `n = 3`...

Comment: Do intersections have to be contiguous to be counted as 1 region? For example, say we've got n=3: the first two quads are coincident (0,0)->(5,5), while the third cuts across them by running (-1,2)->(6,3). That's clearly one k=3 region, but is it one or two k=2 regions?

Comment: @ryanm No, intersections don't have to be contiguous to be counted as one region. You're right, there is clearly one `k = 3` region and two `k = 2` regions.

Comment: Cool problem! Belongs more in mathoverflow than stackoverflow, IMHO, you'lll get a quicker answer there.

Comment: Also I don't think it's a geometrical problem: all that matters is whether i-th rectangle intersect j-th rectangle, and if you abstract out that info you get a combinatorial problem. I think it boils down to counting certain Young's Skew-Tableaux, where each tableau entry (i,j) denotes whether i-th rectangle intersects j-th rectangle. The transitivity that if i-th rectangle doesn't intersect j-th rectangle than ith rectangle doesn't intersect j+1st rectangle is encoded in the nature of skew-tableax. The regions of length k correspond to skew-tableaux rows of width k.

Comment: @Michael Thank's a lot for that hint so far, it sounds very promising! I'm going to look at this in detail and give you a feedback.

Comment: It's not clear to me why this isn't a geometrical problem. If the i-th and the j-th rectangle intersect, why don't the other rectangles play any role? If 1 intersects 2, it is important whether or not 3 intersects 1 and 2?
As far as I unterstand, Young's Skew-Tableaux are used to visualize partitions of non-negative integers. So, for example, the partition of 3 is 3, 1+2, 1+1+1 and p(3)=3. How do a partition of n relate to my problem? If I visualize the partition of 3 I get 1 region where 3 rectanges overlap, 1 for k=2 and 1 for k=1...?

Comment: @MaxWell, that's too long, let me put it into an answer.

Comment: @Michael Thank's again for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

A WRONG answer; not removed only because of the approach that may or may not be useful.

The geometric data -- which rectangles intersect -- can be abstracted away: all that matters is the following property:

Property P: If rectangles i and j intersect that implies that i intersects with i+1,...,j-1 as well.

If your representation of the problem encodes P it doesn't matter anymore that you started with the rectangles.

Now, how do we keep record which rectangles intersect? One way would be a graph with nodes being the rectangles and edges intersections, but that isn't very useful because the above property P is not evident in a graph. A better way would be to setup the following matrix:

Represent i-th rectangle with the i-th row of a matrix A that has 0s until the entry A(i,i), 1s from A(i,i) to A(i,i+m), where i+m is the index of the furthest rectangle that intersects with rectangle i. That is, A has n rows, one per the original rectangle, it consists of 0s and 1s, and A(i,j) for j>i is 1 if and only if rectangles i and j intersect. For j

Now, what does it mean that we have an area of exactly k intersecting rectangle? I claim that the above matrix represents that by a column that has exactly k 1s. Why? Suppose that your area is an intersection of rectangles i+1,...,i+k. Take a look at the matrix entry A(i+k,i+k). The column above it has 1s in rows from 1+1 to i+k and 0s otherwise.

The above matrix looks superficially similar to young's skew-tableau, thus the comment. But yes, similarity is superficial because it doesn't originate from a partition.

Now it remains to maximize the number of columns in A that has exactly k 1s. I think the best one would be a matrix with exactly k 1s in each row, which would give the answer to the original problem n. The answer is obviously wrong, so I'm missing something here. Aaaaah!

Comment: I think my problem is not transitive - the property P can't be hold for any cases. Imagine that the n rectangles are aligned in kind of a 'cirlce' where the i-th rectangle intersects the (i + 1)-th. Now set i = 1 and j = n (the first and the last rectangle). They do intersect but there exist rectangles in between them which don't intersect the first rectangle...

Comment: BTW I think you're missing the region where only 2 & 3 overlap. To get this region, it isn't sufficient to intersect only rectangle 2 and 3; you also need to take the first rectangle into account.

Answer (score 0):

Build a matrix where the cell `Aij` is `1` if rectangles `i` and `j` intersect or `0` if they don't. This matrix is symmetric.

Now notice that many `1`'s close to the diagonal mean more intersections between contiguous-aligned rectangles.

The "worst" case, where `k`, the number of rectangles that intersect each other, is maximum, is represented in the matrix by `k` contiguous `1`'s, with no `0` in between. You can consider the elements *after* the diagonal. This way the property "rectangle `i` intersects rectangle `j`" is fulfilled.

The problem is how to swap rows and columns to achieve this result. It may be a **matrix bandwidth reduction** problem.
See, for example, [this](http://ciprian-zavoianu.blogspot.com.es/2009/01/project-bandwidth-reduction.html) and [this](https://www.degruyter.com/downloadpdf/j/awutm.2014.52.issue-2/awutm-2014-0019/awutm-2014-0019.pdf).

You can also generate your own algorithm for your special case. Be aware of it can be a NP problem, and that several solutions may exist.

Comment: I'm looking for a global solution, not for a specific alignment of n rectangles. So I can't build a matrix as I don't know the coordinates of the rectangles. With your approach I think I'm forced to test all possible configurations of A?

Comment: @MaxWell If you don't know coordinates, how do you tell intersections apart from contiguous ones?

Comment: I need to find an alignment of `n` rectangles under the criteria that they pair-wise intersect AND the number of regions where exactly `k` rectangles intersects reaches its maximum (where the theoretical maximum is `n over k`).

Comment: @MaxWell You didn't answered my question about coordinates; without them how do you find regions? About that theoretical maximum, is it a requirement or just a thought on your own?

Comment: I only need the number of possibilities; the maximum number of regions where exactly `k` rectangles overlap. If I'm able to construct such a worst-case alignment I know the the maximum too. That's the idea.

Comment: It's like "take some (`n`) rectangles and align them in a way so that the mentioned requirements are fulfilled"...

Comment: @MaxWell It seems to me you're getting into a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Yes, it seems so. I will update my question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I have updated the question. Is it now a little bit clearer?